# Apache Ignite client reconnection on Server restartup

Tags: java, client, ignite, reconnect

**I am using Apache Ignite for caching purpose and running server on single node only initializing Ignite client using this code:-**

```
public class IgniteUtil {

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(IgniteUtil.class.getName());


    public static boolean initializeIgniteClient() {

        try{    
            String hostName="localhost:47500..47509";

            logger.info("Connecting to Apache ignite Server with host:port=" + hostName);           
            TcpDiscoverySpi spi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
            IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
            TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder finder =new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder();
            List<String>addressList=new ArrayList<>();
            addressList.add(hostName);
            finder.setAddresses(addressList);
            spi.setIpFinder(finder);

            spi.setJoinTimeout(600);
            cfg.setDiscoverySpi(spi);
            cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);
            Ignition.setClientMode(true);
            URL xml = U.resolveIgniteUrl("log4j2.xml", false);
            IgniteLogger log = new Log4J2Logger(xml);
            cfg.setGridLogger(log);
            Ignition.start(cfg);
            if(!Ignition.ignite().cluster().forServers().nodes().isEmpty())
            {           
                logger.info("Connecting to Apache ignite Server SUCCESS with hostName="+hostName);
                return true;
            }else{
                logger.error("Connecting to Apache ignite Server FAILED with hostName="+hostName);
                return false;
            }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            logger.error("Connection to Apache ignite Server failed...",e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

    }
```

**Assuming when ignite server gets down an exception is thrown and client reconnection is attempted using below code.
Every attempt to reconnect server gives latency of around 20 sec till server is down. How can I overcome this problem in best possible way?**

```
catch(Exception e)
        {
            if(e instanceof CacheException) {
                if (e.getCause() instanceof
                        IgniteClientDisconnectedException)
                {
                    Ignition.stop(true);
                    IgniteUtil.initializeIgniteClient();
                    logger.info("Reattempt failed");
                }else if (e.getCause() instanceof
                        IgniteClientDisconnectedCheckedException) {
                    Ignition.stop(true);
                    IgniteUtil.initializeIgniteClient();
                    logger.info("Reattempt failed");
                }else if (e.getCause() instanceof
                        NodeStoppingException) {
                    Ignition.stop(true);
                    IgniteUtil.initializeIgniteClient();
                    logger.info("Reattempt failed");
                }else{
                    // nothing to do as not related to ignite server shutdown       
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if(e instanceof IllegalStateException) {
                Ignition.stop(true);
                IgniteUtil.initializeIgniteClient();
                logger.info("Reattempt failed");
            }else{
                // nothing to do as not related to ignite server shutdown           }
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If server goes down, client will throw `IgniteClientDisconnectedException`, it has a future, that will be completed when client reconnects to server again:
`IgniteClientDisconnectedException.reconnectFuture().get()`.

Comment: that will be blocking i guess, will not allow other operations unless done in separate thread...As per my understanding OP wants to keep trying reconnection with each cache hit till server comes up and application keep working....that check whether server up or not taking 20 seconds as doing actual reconnection...there should be better way for this check till ignite bug gets resolved https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-2766

Comment: Will IgniteClientDisconnectedException.reconnectFuture().get() keep application suspended untill I connect to server ? if yes, then this is not requirement , application should run even if server is down. Please provide any other alternative if possible . Thanks.

Comment: You're not required to block on this future, it's just a convenient way to wait for reconnection. If you don't wait, any Ignite operation will throw an exception until client is reconnected, so you just need to handle this exception in a way that satisfies your requirements.